# FlowTexView dynamically added text appear in single line height issue

Tags: android, layout

I have added flowtextview jar file in my project lib folder and its working perfectly when i add it in my layout manualy.

I need to add flowtextview dynamically to my LinearLayout and add text and images dynamicaly into it. I can add text and images but the text appearing in sinle line, i thing its because of the flowtexview height setting issue.

please check the attached image , you can see the issue correctly.

code used for adding dynamic views as follows,

```
            contentHolder = (LinearLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.contentOuter);
        //add LayoutParams
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //params.setMargins(10, 20, 10, 20); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        contentHolder.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ftv = new FlowTextView(getActivity());

        FlowTextView.LayoutParams fp = new FlowTextView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        fp.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10); 
        ftv.setLayoutParams(params);
        ftv.setId(110);
        ftv.setText("Currently it is placing that image as the background to the view and not the actual image in it.Currently it is placing that image as the background to the view and not the actual image in it.Currently it is placing that image as the background to the view and not the actual image in it..");

        ImageView im = new ImageView(getActivity());
        im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.av1);
        im.setId(5);

        RelativeLayout rt = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        rparams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
        rt.setLayoutParams(rparams);
        rt.addView(im);

        ftv.addView(rt);
        ftv.invalidate();


        //add the textView and the Button to LinearLayout
        contentHolder.addView(ftv);
```

[image: flowtextview text display issue]

Comment: I Think  This is Background Color Issue Change the color of Background at  text...

Comment: no i have checked it with static flowtextviews. text overlapping due to height issue, i think so, but i dont know where it can fix

Comment: Have You Try multiple Lines or Max Line 4 or 5  in TextView as Per Need

Comment: its not TextView its FlowTextView.

Comment: you should make it as multiple Lines in height which is in single Line so do it programmatically..... We Have not your Library so we can not implement it do it programmatically it Will Solve....

Answer (score 0):

at last i found the issue, its because of the jar file. its not an updated one. use flowtextview as a library project and add it to your project or use or Gradle:

compile 'uk.co.deanwild:flowtextview:2.0.2@aar'